# Angular [class] binding not working on Component initialization

Tags: angular

I've got an Angular Component with a `sortBy` property that can have one of three values. The `changeSort` function sets the value, which applies the class `active` to one of three list items:

```
  <ul>
     <li role="button" [class.active]="sortBy === 'newest'" id="newest" (click)="changeSort($event)">Newest</li>
     <li role="button" [class.active]="sortBy === 'oldest'" id="oldest" (click)="changeSort($event)">Oldest</li>
     <li role="button" [class.active]="sortBy === 'alpha'"  id="alpha"  (click)="changeSort($event)">Alphabetical</li>
  </ul>
```

This all works fine. What's not working is that the class is not being applied when the component is initialized. I've tried setting `sortBy` in `ngOnInit` and in `ngAfterViewInit` and neither causes the class to be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [StackBlitz](https://starter-angular.stackblitz.io) I've just made to see if it's something you want to achieve.

Takeaway is to give the `sortBy` a default value on initialization, not in any life-cycle hook.

Comment: This works, but I'm still confused. I'm loading the setting from localStorage through a service, and I thought doing complex stuff like that in a constructor was a bad idea?

Comment: How your service and your whole component's code look like?